# Syntax highlighting - argument names

Tags: r, syntax-highlighting, rstudio, knitr

Is there a way in RStudio to make the names of function calls a separate color? For example, in `mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)` the `na.rm` part would appear green (or whatever color)? I looked in options > appearance, but none of those themes seem to do it.

In particular, I'd like the source code in RStudio to have the same highlighting as it does if I compile a document in `knitr`, for example.

Thanks!

Comment: By "names of function calls" do you mean the parameter names when calling a function?

Comment: @Dason Yes, that's what I mean